# python kivy - on_press being executed twice

Tags: python, kivy, touch, raspberry-pi3

Newbie to Python - I am writing a raspberry pi app with touch screen. Manage to make it work but the Increment function is being executed twice when pressing the + button (same for decrement). These buttons are enabled only while another button is pressed but this is not the problem. 
Any help please?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.show_cursor = False
import serial
import time

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=19200, timeout=3.0)

btnNum = '0'
b1Tmp = 0; b2Tmp = 0; b3Tmp = 0; b4Tmp = 0; b5Tmp = 0; b6Tmp = 0; b7Tmp = 0; b8Tmp = 0
b1Max =50; b2Max =50; b3Max =50; b4Max =50; b5Max =50; b6Max =50; b7Max =50; b8Max =50;


class Container(Widget):
    labR1= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR2= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR3= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR4= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR5= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR6= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR7= ObjectProperty(None)
    labR8= ObjectProperty(None)
    butUP= ObjectProperty(None)
    butDN= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM1= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM2= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM3= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM4= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM5= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM6= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM7= ObjectProperty(None)
    labM8= ObjectProperty(None)



    def bpressed(self,instance):
        global btnNum
        btnNum = instance.text
        self.butDN.disabled = False
        self.butUP.disabled = False

    def breleased(self,instance):
        global btnNum
        btnNum = '0'
        self.butDN.disabled = True
        self.butUP.disabled = True

    def increment(self,instance):
        global btnNum,b1Max,b2Max,b3Max,b4Max,b5Max,b6Max,b7Max,b8Max
        if (btnNum == '1'):
            if (b1Max<100): b1Max+=2
            self.labM1.text = str(b1Max)
        if (btnNum == '2'):
            if (b2Max<100): b2Max=b2Max+1
            self.labM2.text = str(b2Max)
        if (btnNum=='3'):
            if (b3Max<100): b3Max+=1
            self.labM3.text = str(b3Max)
        if (btnNum=='4'):
            if (b4Max<100): b4Max+=1
            self.labM4.text = str(b4Max)
        if (btnNum=='5'):
            if (b5Max<100): b5Max+=1
            self.labM5.text = str(b5Max)
        if (btnNum=='6'):
            if (b6Max<100): b6Max+=1
            self.labM6.text = str(b6Max)
        if (btnNum=='7'):
            if (b7Max<100): b7Max+=1
            self.labM7.text = str(b7Max)
        if (btnNum=='8'):
            if (b8Max<100): b8Max+=1
            self.labM8.text = str(b8Max)

    def decrement(self,instance):
        global btnNum,b1Max,b2Max,b3Max,b4Max,b5Max,b6Max,b7Max,b8Max
        if (btnNum == '1'):
            if (b1Max>20): b1Max-=1
            self.labM1.text = str(b1Max)
        if (btnNum == '2'):
            if (b2Max>20): b2Max-=1
            self.labM2.text = str(b2Max)
        if (btnNum=='3'):
            if (b3Max>20): b3Max-=1
            self.labM3.text = str(b3Max)
        if (btnNum=='4'):
            if (b4Max>20): b4Max-=1
            self.labM4.text = str(b4Max)
        if (btnNum=='5'):
            if (b5Max>20): b5Max-=1
            self.labM5.text = str(b5Max)
        if (btnNum=='6'):
            if (b6Max>20): b6Max-=1
            self.labM6.text = str(b6Max)
        if (btnNum=='7'):
            if (b7Max>20): b7Max-=1
            self.labM7.text = str(b7Max)
        if (btnNum=='8'):
            if (b8Max>20): b8Max-=1
            self.labM8.text = str(b8Max)


    def  serialsend(self,instance):
        port.write("\r\nSay something:".encode())

    def close(self , obj):
        App.get_running_app().stop()
        Window.close()



class BoilerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Boiler Monitor'
        return Container()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.fullscreen = True
    app = BoilerApp()
    app.run()
```

kv file

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    color: .8,.9,0,1
    font_size: 30

<MyLabel@Label>:
    color: .8,.9,0,1
    font_size: 30


<Container>

    labR1: labR1
    labR2: labR2
    labR3: labR3
    labR4: labR4
    labR5: labR5
    labR6: labR6
    labR7: labR7
    labR8: labR8

    butUP: butUP
    butDN: butDN

    labM1: labM1
    labM2: labM2
    labM3: labM3
    labM4: labM4
    labM5: labM5
    labM6: labM6
    labM7: labM7
    labM8: labM8


    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height
        Label:
            text: "Boiler Alarm"
            size_hint: .5, .2
            font_size: 40
            background_color: 1,0,0,1
        GridLayout:
            cols:10
            MyLabel:
                text: "Boiler"
            MyButton:
                id: butB1
                text: "1"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB2
                text: "2"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB3
                text: "3"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB4
                text: "4"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB5
                text: "5"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB6
                text: "6"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB7
                text: "7"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyButton:
                id: butB8
                text: "8"
                on_press: root.bpressed(self)
                on_release: root.breleased(self)
            MyLabel:
                text: ""
            Label:
                text: "Reading"
                font_size: 25
            MyLabel:
                id: labR1
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR2
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR3
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR4
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR5
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR6
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR7
                text: "0"
            MyLabel:
                id: labR8
                text: "0"
            MyButton:
                id: butUP
                text: "+"
                disabled: True
                on_press: root.increment(self)

            Label:
                text: "Minimum"
                font_size: 25
            MyLabel:
                id: labM1
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM2
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM3
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM4
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM5
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM6
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM7
                text: "50"
            MyLabel:
                id: labM8
                text: "50"
            MyButton:
                id: butDN
                text: "-"
                disabled: True
                on_release: root.decrement(self)

        Button:
            id: btnexit
            text: "Exit"
            size_hint: .5, .1
            on_press: root.close(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found multiple workarounds after fighting this for a while.

The issue seems to be that kivy interprets both the *mouse* and the *touch* events simultaneously. This means when you touch the display both a "mouse" click and a "touch" press event is fired, resulting in double presses.

## Solution 1 – change the kivy config.ini

The easiest fix is to edit the `[input]`-section in `~/.kivy/config.ini` in su a way:

```
[input]
%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
mouse = mouse
# mtdev_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=mtdev 
hid_%(name)s = probesysfs,provider=hidinput
```

Just comment out the line starting with `mtdev_` and restart the program.

## Solution 2 – manually check the event-kind

If you want to use the mouse somewhere still, there is a different way to do this. Let's assume you create a button somewhere like this:

```py
button = ToggleButton(text="Cool Button")
button.bind(on_release=on_toggle)
self.add_widget(button)
```

You can then check whether our `on_toggle`-function is activated by a mouse- or a touch-event as follows:

```py
from kivy.input.providers.mouse import MouseMotionEvent

def on_toggle(button_instance):
    if isinstance(button_instance.last_touch, MouseMotionEvent):
        print(f"Last Touch was from the Mouse {button_instance.last_touch}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use timeout with kivy. You should instead use the Clock function. The timeout function would halt all your program which may lead to these issues. Whereas Clock schedules specific events without halting the program altogether.